# Bluetooth headphones paired, and yet, system sound is partly played through the main speaker. How to get any system sound only in the headphones?

Tags: windows, windows-10, speakers, headphones, system-sounds

This is needed since in a calm room with other people, you do not want to have the system sound popping up as soon as you press a key that is not allowed at that time.

On Windows 10, with Bluetooth headphones paired, the system sound is partly played through the main speaker.

When I just turn up or down the sound, the system sound to that (a small jingle that is played) will be heard in the BT headphones. But when I press a button that is not allowed or at any other error that leads to a jingle, you hear the system sound jingle through the main speakers even though the BT headphones are paired and you listen to music or videos at the same time.

How to get any system sound only in the headphones?

Comment: What about selecting the BT headphones as the sound output (assuming it's correctly paired)?

Comment: Bluetooth headphones cannot be *plugged in*. Please describe the situation and what you tried in greater detail.

Comment: @DanielB changed that. Well, I did not try anything. I only checked the sound settings to see that I could not quickly find out whether there are settings only for error jingles to say that these should be played by the system speakers instead of any other output.

Comment: It's possible to disable certain system sounds totally everywhere, if that is a possible solution.

Comment: @harrymc yes it is. I would be fine with that workaround. Could become an answer if you ask me.

Comment: In the taskbar there is a speaker symbol. Have you clicked on that and selected the Bluetooth as output?

Comment: @cliff2310 Yes, it is the output, and still, some error sound comes through the system speaker.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To disable some Windows sounds totally :

- Run *Control Panel > Sound*
- If you are still in this menu, click on the "sound control panel" on the right again:

[image]

- Position to the "Sounds" tab

[image]

- Locate and click your sound by its name (as much as possible),
  for example perhaps "Device Connect" (or here: Systembenachrichtigung = system alert)
- Check by playing that this is indeed the right sound by clicking
  "Test"
- Note down the current sound file of the sound (here: "Windows Background"), to be able to later
  undo the change
- Set the drop-down box to `(None)`, here: "(Kein)"

[image]

- Click OK.